# How to show last five facebook Posts and Tweeter tweets On Website

Tags: facebook, twitter, web

I am designing a website where i have to add the last 5 posts from the facebook page of the organization and similarly from twitter also.Now i searched on the web for the same but did not get the way to proceed .So my question is how to do the same for my website.
Please help me.

After some More search i got this Code ..

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYOURPOSTURL&amp;width=490&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=435" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:320px; height:300px; background: white; float:left; " allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It is displaying my facebook post easily in my web page but i am not able to like any of the post.Is is not possible to like it from here or i am missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Twitter, you could use the Embedded Timeline: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

For Facebook, you can requests the Page Feed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/) either on the frontend side with the JavaScript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0), or on the backend with direct API calls.

Comment: What has the Like Box to do with displaying Page Posts?

Comment: Ok I got it.Now one query ,in the given code why is my scroll getting ended after the height of the iframe source.Actually i need to show all the post of my facebook page ..Is this because of HTML or something else?

Comment: I answered your question. This is another question. Please read about the basics first. The Like Box will not help you displaying Page Post.  Period.